# Kinect Skeleton Tracking for 2 people

Tags: kinect

I want to use Kinect sensor to develop a application, what I want to accomplish is to differentiate between Skeleton of two people, and use only one which is required and ignore the other,can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Kinect identifies the closest skeleton first but if you want to pick the skeleton with user specific condition like a specific color on the user then its a kind of image processing too.

Answer (score 0):

The Kinect SDK assigns a tracking ID to each skeleton that it detects: you can use that number to tell apart who's who. So, after you pick a user, you can store his tracking ID and later, find in the skeleton array the one with the matching tracking ID. If it is not found, it means that the user has left the scene (or the Kinect stopped seeing him for other reason, like somebody walked in front of him).